# Django UnicodeDecodeError after migrating to python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-2.7, unicode

I am migrating project from django 1.11 to django 2 and have the following problem. After migration from python 2.7 to python 3.6 on django 1.11 there are a lot of `UnicodeDecodeError's`
when im trying to get some data by the ORM. For example:

```
class JournalName(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    par_id = models.ForeignKey('Journal', db_column='par_id')
    parent = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, db_column=u'name')
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'journal_name'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

following print :

```
print(JournalName.objects.all())
```

results with error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0142' in position 768: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Project is using MySQL database with utf8. I was trying to debug this but i have no idea what could cause the problem. On python 2.7 everything works ok so maybe there is something left in code that i should change compared to py2?
I had to delete some option in db settings which caused other errors but maybe it has something with this:

```
'OPTIONS': {
   "init_command": "set names latin1;",
}
```

Comment: see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: Ok, but i cannot encode Django QuerySet. I think IT is related with settings or something

Comment: on your model definition, what does the '____str____' function look like?

Comment: Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you are using ASCII locale (e.g. 'C' or 'POSIX').

You can print non-ASCII string by:

- Use UTF-8 locales (e.g. 'en_US.UTF-8', 'C.UTF-8', etc...)
- Set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8' environment variable. But note that this only changes the stdio encoding.

But I strongly recommend to upgrade Python 3.7+. Since Python 3.7:

- Python tries to change the locale to C.UTF-8 (See [PEP 538](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0538/)) automatically when you are using 'C' or 'POSIX' locale.
- If there is no "C.UTF-8" locale, Python enables UTF-8 mode automatically (See [PEP 540](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0540/)).

So you can use UTF-8 more easily.